# Why $(0)$ and $spec(k)$ is $R$-scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

Let $R$ be a DVR, whose residue field is $k$ and $p$ is it's uniformizer.
Then, generic fiber and special fiber of a given scheme is defined as fiber product of $X$ and $(0)$ and $Spec(k)$.But fiber product is defined between $R$-schemes.
Could you give me an explanation why $(0)$ and $Spec(k)$ is $R$-scheme ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K=\operatorname{Frac}R$ and $k=R/p$. There are natural homomorphisms $R\to K$ and $R\to k$. These induce morphisms on spectra in the usual way. In other words, $\operatorname{Spec} K$ and $\operatorname{Spec} k$ are $R$-schemes.

Now, if $X$ is an $R$-scheme, the generic fiber is defined to be
$$X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}R} \operatorname{Spec} K,$$
and the special fiber is
$$X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}R} \operatorname{Spec} k.$$

These are homeomorphic to the inverse image (i.e. fiber) above $(0)$ and $(p)$ respectively, under the structural morphism of $X$.

Comment: My book's definition of Special fiber is $$X\times_{\operatorname{Spec}R} p$$ where $p$ is maximal ideal of $R$. Then , I cannot write $p$ in the form like Spec●, so I 'm confused.